# My sourdough starter is thick with small bubbles but isn't rising

Tags: baking, sourdough, sourdough-starter, rising, starter

I started my sourdough starter on the 17th. I was doing 1/2 cup water, 1/2 cup flour with one feeding a day, discarding half before each feeding. It rose with bubbles the first two days and then began having hooch every day. I started feeding it twice a day on the 23rd (which would have been day 6). On the 24th I switched to 1/2 cup flour and 1/3 cup water to get rid of the hooch and create a thicker consistency. Since switching to the different amount and continuing to feed twice a day, the starter is thick with bubbles on the top but still isn't rising. Should I start over? Should I be patient? Today is day 9 and I am one feeding in. Please help!

Comment: As a recommendation, you might want to try feeding it only once a day.  I've done a number of  starters, and feeding twice a day only makes sense if the starter is in a very warm place (26-32C).  You could be turning it over so fast that the culture doesn't really have time to grow.

Comment: I will only feed it once today instead of twice and see how that works!

Comment: as an aside, sourdough starters work equally well with a tablespoon or two as with half a cup, but you waste way less flour that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an American one: you are feeding equal volumes instead of weights. Since water is a lot denser than flour, this results in a very liquid sour dough.

Since it is liquid, it can't really rise, it needs to be thicker for that.

Switch to feed equal weights of flour and water, and you should get a thicker, rising sourdough.